# Нахождение общих точек, по которым можно соединить бары

Tags: python

Хочу реализовать в Python фильтр, который показывает наличие возможности проведения любой прямой линии через точки баров/интервальных значений (по факту имеются только числовые/ценовые данные верхней и нижней точек этих баров) - см. прикрепленный рисунок.

Есть понимание, что надо найти наименьший бар и на его основе оперировать как то дальше (строить линии через точки данного бара/интервала), а может и вообще по другому находить общие точки соприкосновения.

Прошу помочь построить алгоритм, поскольку уже 2 недели бьюсь и понимаю, что не хватает мат аппарата.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот данных, на которых рисунок построен в Excel:

```
210,63/207,01
218,3/210,09
222,83/216
222,45/217,1
224,54/216,85
227,59/221,61
231,24/228,2
232,25/228
```

Comment: В общем случае не всегда возможно найти такую прямую, которая будет пересекать __все__ интервалы. Если я правильно понял вопрос - вам нужно взять центры интервалов и построить линейную регрессию по этим центрам...

Comment: Не обязательно линия должна по центрам проходить. Если такую линию построить не возможно, то это тоже результат, который меня устраивает, т.к. мне нужно узнать ответ на вопрос - можно ли через точки данных ценовых отрезков провести общую линию?

Comment: я не предлагал проводить линию по центрам интервалов - я предложил построить линейную регрессию на основе центров интервалов, т.е. найти прямую которая будет проходить наиболее близко ко __всем__ центрам интервалов. PS если возможно построить несколько таких прямых - по какому алгоритму вы будете выбирать нужную прямую?

Comment: Попробовал построить на основе центров интервалов линейную регрессию. Получил R^2=0.94. А что дальше то? Вот в чем вопрос. Большое значение R^2, конечно, хорошо, но оно не гарантирует мне того, что прямая линия пересекает эти бары.

Comment: А в чем прикладной смысл задачи?

Comment: Поиск плотного движения. Например, если бы бары находились горизонтально, то это поиск скопления баров, которые не "разбегаются". Я понимаю, что можно и регрессию подключить, но проведение линии, как в вопросе, меня давно уже гнетет.